# How to put data from MySQL to Kafka producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am a fresher in Big Data.
I have database in MySQL and I don't know how to import this to Apache Kafka for streaming process.
And then get data from consumer.
Please give me advice.

Comment: Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with more information, sample code, and the steps you have taken so far. This information will make it more likely that someone can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding putting mysql data into kafka I'd suggest having a look at [the kafka-connect jdbc connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc).

Next, you have a flurry of stream processing frameworks, with their own benefits and drawbacks, to choose from in order to do computation on your streaming data stored in kafka:

- [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) and in particular Spark streaming
- [Apache Flink](http://flink.apache.org)
- [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org)
- [Kafka streams](http://www.confluent.io/blog/introducing-kafka-streams-stream-processing-made-simple)

Comment: try "http://debezium.io/" -> This is also one of the good connector we are using.